# Selects with same names

Tags: javascript, php

By clicking on the button to add additional selects the same name, I need to replace them so that you can pick up on php array.

```
document.querySelector('#add').onclick = function () {
    thespan = document.createElement('span');
    thespan.innerHTML = '
        <select name="fruit">
            <option value="apple">apple</option>
            <option value="Banana">banana</option>
            <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
        </select>
        <select name="pos">
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>';
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(thespan, this.nextSibling);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you need and incremental `id` on the `select` so that they're unique?

Comment: I need names like name="fruits[0]", name="pos[0]" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the array selector on your select name. Like:

```
<select name="fruits[]"></select>
```

Comment: $arr=array($_POST['fruit[0]'],$_POST['pos[0]']);
$arr1=array($_POST['fruit[1]'],$_POST['pos[1]']);
$pass=implode(' ',$arr);
$pass1=implode(' ',$arr1); I echo it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Do `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` and see how your selects got posted.

Comment: All responses are good: Array ( [email] => dyadyadyavaleras@gmail.com [fruit] => Array ( [0] => apple [1] => apple ) [pos] => Array ( [0] => right [1] => left ). I echo '<h1>Pass='.$pass.$pass1.'</h1>';

Comment: Then your results are `$_POST['fruit'][0]`, `$_POST['fruit'][1]`, `$_POST['pos'][0]`, `$_POST['pos'][1]` and so on.

Comment: With pleasure. Cheers.